# How to create a search button or how to Rowfilter database using textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I used the codes available on youtube. both of them arent working

```
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

command.CommandText = "select * from Table2 where Last_Name ='" + textBox12 + "'";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

connection.Close();
```

there will be a error message saying that the

> 'column is not found' or' missing operand'

Comment: What is the structure of `Table2`?  Also this is open to SQL injection, which may not practically be a risk here if it's a desktop application using an Access database, but in general and for the sake of establishing secure coding habits, you should never directly concatenate user input into a query.

Comment: what is `textBox12` ? If its a textbox than this does not compile because it then should be `textBox12.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Textbox12.Text, and use Like instead of =

More readable as: $"select * from Table2 where Last_Name Like '{Textbox12.Text}' ;

Comment: what is the value of `Textbox12.Text` ? Could it be there is a comma `,` in there ? Or a qoute `'` ?

Comment: Ah, good suggestion. Could use Replace(Textbox12.Text, "'", "''") to handle single quotes